# How to join a table to itself and get max row then connect another table to it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains redundant entries. What i need is to
get the column with max id data, then connect the table to users table and get name based on the max row user_id

```
tracking table

 id | labref | user_id
 -----------------------
 1  |   a    |  1
 ------------------------
 2  |   a    |  3
 ------------------------
 3  |   b    |  4
 ------------------------
 5  |   b    |  7
 ------------------------
```

SQL Query:

```
 SELECT id,labref,user_id FROM tracking_table t WHERE t.id = 
 (SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM tracking_table t2, user u WHERE t.labref = t2.labref AND u.id = t2.user_id)
```

Result:

```
 id | labref | user_id
 --------------------
 2  |   a    |  3
 --------------------
 5  |   b    |  7
 --------------------
```

Would like to join users table below

```
 Users Table

 id  |  name
 -------------
 1  |   ua  
 ------------
 2  |   ub   
 ------------
 3  |   uc  
 ------------
 4  |   ud  
 ------------
 5  |   ue    
 -------------
 7  |   uf   
 -------------
```

Desired results should be as follows:

```
  id | labref | name
 --------------------
 2  |   a    |  uc
 --------------------
 5  |   b    |  uf
 --------------------
```

Suggestions as to where I am now stuck?

Comment: I had to edit the question because your expected output had a typo.  It should be users `uc` and `uf` in the expected result set.

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find the maximum `id` value for each lab reference.  Then, join to this subquery to leave you with the effective rows you want.  Finally, join this to the user table to bring in the usernames.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.labref,
    u.name
FROM tracking_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT labref, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM tracking_table
    GROUP BY labref
) t2
    ON t1.labref = t2.labref AND
       t1.id     = t2.max_id
INNER JOIN user_table u
    ON t1.user_id = u.id
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Please check this statement. Does it fit your needs?

```
SELECT t.id, t.labref, u.name 
FROM tracking_table t 
INNER JOIN users u 
    on t.user_id = u.id 
WHERE t.id = 
     (SELECT MAX(t2.id) 
      FROM tracking_table t2, user u 
      WHERE t.labref = t2.labref AND u.id = t2.user_id)
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The users table is unnecessary in the subquery. You need it in the main query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.labref, u.name 
FROM tracking_table t 
JOIN user u ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE t.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM tracking_table t2 WHERE t.labref = t2.labref);
```

You shouldn't use comma-separated joins anymore by the way. They were made redundant in 1992. Use explicit ANSI joins instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but mysql returns an error

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't2.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Copy and paste error. It must be `t.user_id` of course.